# Curvature tensor on the sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, curvature

While reading R. Hamilton paper "Three-manifolds with positive Ricci curvature" I came across the sentence:

For the sphere we have
$$R(u,v,u,v)=R_{ijkl}u^{i}v^{j}u^{k}v^{l}>0,$$

which is the oposite of the usual convention, but more symmetric. The Ricci curvature is the contraction
$$R_{ik}=g^{jl}R_{ijkl},$$
and on the sphere we have 
$$R(u,u)=R_{ij}u^{i}u^{j}.$$

What I'm strugling with is that part where

"for the sphere we have $R(u,v,u,v)=R_{ijkl}u^{i}v^{j}u^{k}v^{l}>0$."

Could some one explain me why is that so? Or any link that explains this? Is it just saying how curvature tensor acts on the tangent vectors of the sphere?

Comment: To me it seems that he is just pointing out, that he uses the more uncommon definition of curvature tensor $R_{XY}Z = \nabla_Y\nabla_XZ - \nabla_X\nabla_YZ - \nabla_{[Y,X]}Z$ which is the negative of the common definition (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor). Thus sectional curvature is given by $R(u,v,u,v)$ in contrast to the common $R(u,v,v,u)$.

Comment: Are you asking about his sign convention or more than that? if it's about sign, there are some sign differences in the literature concerning the full curvature tensor , although everybody (like Hamilton in the quote you give) arranges his signs so  that the sectional and scalar curvature of a round sphere is positive...